# Getting hibernate persistence-unit classes from both ORM and OGM

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, orm, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to use both of hibernate's orm and ogm in the same application.
In my `persistence.xml` I have two `persistence-unit`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="orm-mysql">
        ...
        <class>...</class>
        ...
        <class>...</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="ogm-mongodb" transaction-type="JTA">
        ...
        <class>...</class>
        ...
        <class>...</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
    ...
</persistence>
```

I want to use the hibernate orm native api with both orm and ogm, and so I need to add the annotated classes to two different `MetadataSources`.
Since I have the persistence units I thought that I can do this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("orm-mysql");
Set<ManagedType<?>> managedTypes = entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getManagedTypes();
for (ManagedType type : managedTypes) {
    ormSources.addAnnotatedClass(type.getJavaType());
}

entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-mongo");
managedTypes = entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getManagedTypes();
for (ManagedType type : managedTypes) {
    ogmSources.addAnnotatedClass(type.getJavaType());
}
```

The problem is that in the first iteration, of the orm classes, I get both the orm and ogm classes that are included in `orm-mysql` and `ogm-mongo`.
The second time around it's fine though, I get only the `ogm-mongo` classes.

Can't figure out what's wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone makes this stupid mistake as well, I had:

```
<persistence-unit name="orm-mysql">
    ...
    <class>...</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Removing the `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property solved the problem.